# Assigning different lifetimes to a single variable

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545670/multiple-mutable-references-in-a-loop) trying to understand Rust ownership and lifetimes, and I'm confused by this piece of code:

```rs
struct Foo {
    x: String,
}

fn get_x<'a, 'b>(a: &'a Foo, b: &'b Foo) -> &'b str {
    let mut bar = &a.x;
    bar = &b.x;
    bar
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab21d9609b6eb04199f34781df857540)</sup>

This code does *not* compile, because `data from 'a' is returned`. I assume this is because when I initialized `bar`, I assigned a `&'a` reference to it, so Rust assumes that `bar` has lifetime `'a`. So when I try to return a value of type `&'a str` it complains that it does not match the return type `'b str`.

What I don't understand is: Why am I allowed to assign a `&'b str` to `bar` in the first place? If Rust assumes that `bar` has lifetime `'a`, then shouldn't it prevent me from assigning `b.x` to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every borrow has a distinct lifetime. The Rust compiler is always trying to minimize lifetimes, because shorter lifetimes have less chance to intersect with other lifetimes, and this matters especially with mutable borrows (remember, there can only be one active mutable borrow of a particular memory location at any time). The lifetime of a borrow derived from another borrow can be shorter or equal to the other borrow's, but it can never be larger.

Let's examine a variant of your function that doesn't have any errors:

```
fn get_x<'a, 'b>(a: &'a Foo, b: &'b Foo) -> &'b str {
    let mut bar = &a.x;
    bar = &b.x;
    todo!()
}
```

The expressions `&a.x` and `&b.x` create new borrowed references. These references have their own lifetime; let's call them `'ax` and `'bx`. `'ax` borrows from `a`, which has type `&'a Foo`, so `'a` must outlive `'ax` (`'a: 'ax`) – likewise with `'bx` and `'b`. So far, `'ax` and `'bx` are unrelated.

In order to determine the type of `bar`, the compiler must unify `'ax` and `'bx`. Given that `'ax` and `'bx` are unrelated, we must define a new lifetime, `'abx`, as the union of `'ax` and `'bx`, and use this lifetime for the two borrows (replacing/refining `'ax` and `'bx`) and the type of `bar`. This new lifetime needs to carry the constraints from both `'ax` and `'bx`: we now have `'a: 'abx` and `'b: 'abx`. The borrows with lifetime `'abx` don't escape from the function, and lifetimes `'a` and `'b` outlive the call frame by virtue of being lifetime parameters on the function, so the constraints are met.

Now let's get back to your original function:

```
fn get_x<'a, 'b>(a: &'a Foo, b: &'b Foo) -> &'b str {
    let mut bar = &a.x;
    bar = &b.x;
    bar
}
```

Here, we have an additional constraint: the type of `bar` must be compatible with `&'b str`. To do this, we must unify `'abx` and `'b`. Given that we have `'b: 'abx`, the result of this unification is simply `'b`. However, we also have constraint `'a: 'abx`, so we should transfer this constraint onto `'b`, giving `'a: 'b`.

The problem here is that the constraint `'a: 'b` only involves lifetime parameters (instead of anonymous lifetimes). Lifetime constraints form part of a function's contract; adding one is an API breaking change. The compiler can infer some lifetime constraints based on the types used in the function signature, but it will never infer constraints that arise only from the function's implementation (otherwise an implementation change could silently cause an API breaking change). Explicitly adding `where 'a: 'b` to the function signature makes the error go away (though it makes the function more restrictive, i.e. some calls that were valid without the constraint become invalid with the constraint):

```
fn get_x<'a, 'b>(a: &'a Foo, b: &'b Foo) -> &'b str
where
    'a: 'b,
{
    let mut bar = &a.x;
    bar = &b.x;
    bar
}
```

Comment: Much more beautifully explained than I did! And great use of the `todo!()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's correct to assume that `bar` is assigned lifetime `'a` based on the initial assignment.

Rather, `bar` is assigned lifetime `'b` based on the return type. That's why it doesn't complain about assigning something from `b`, but it does complain about assigning something from `a`.

There's a few things you can do to verify a bit more what's going on here.

First, if you promise that `a` lives at least as long as `b`, via
`fn get_x<'a: 'b, 'b>`, the whole program compiles without problem.

Second, to see that the issue is based on type, check out this version of your code: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=17c0ec16eecdcc9d9009691180af9854)

```rust
struct Foo {
    x: String,
}

fn get_x<'a, 'b>(a: &'a Foo, b: &'b Foo) -> &'b str {
    let mut bar: &'_ String = &a.x; // Alternatively try with 'a, 'b or '_ for the lifetime parameter
    bar = &b.x;
    &b.x
}
```

Here we return something that's definitely correct for the lifetime, and just use `bar` to play with explicitly specifying the lifetime parameter. The version I posted compiles, because here the borrow checker just finds a lifetime that encompasses both `'a` and `'b`. But if we replace the `'_` with either `'a` or `'b` it won't compile because now we have a lifetime mismatch when we assign to the same variable from different parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that I'm probably wrong about how lifetimes are calculated here, but I'm still confused. The compiler doesn't complain about assigning something from `a` to `bar` (there's no error associated with that line). And the error message explicitly says that it is returning "data from 'a'", which to me implies that it thinks `bar` (what I'm returning, and the line it is underlining in the error) is "data from 'a'", i.e. it has the same lifetime as `a`.