Rust lifetime unification on function call
I'm trying to understand rust lifetime unification during function calls, I have this example code
fn foo2<'a, 'b: 'a>(a: &'a i32, b: &'b i32) {
    if *a > 0 {
        foo2::<'a, 'a>(b, a); // 1) okay! they use the smaller lifetime
        foo2::<'b, 'a>(b, a); // 2) lifetime may not live long enough consider adding the following bound: `'a: 'b`
        foo2::<'b, 'b>(b, a); // 3) okay!? does this makes a dangling?
        foo2(b, a);           // 4) okay, but what is happening?
    }
}


At 4) I was expecting it to fail with the same error of 2) but no error, I guess Rust is doing the same as in 1), getting the smaller lifetime and using it. Where can I find more info about this?
Also in 3), doesn't this call create a dangling reference in the second parameter? I'm passing
a with lifetime 'b which is bigger than 'a
Reference: An answer saying about unification in lifetimes https://stackoverflow.com/a/69982401/652528

Update: The 3) does not work as pointed out in the comments


fails for me with: argument requires that 'a must outlive 'b.



doesn't compile as @rodrigo noticed - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11d541fddba9894ba2df4e5929eac8b7


Oh, indeed! I didn't get the second error until I commented the first one in the editor, thanks for pointing this out!

When you don't specify the lifetimes, then the compiler will infer them, it does so by picking the smallest possible lifetimes.
For your call 4 foo2(b, a); the smallest possible lifetimes it can pick, are lifetimes that only last for that call essentially it's sugar for foo2<'4, '4>(b, a) where '4 is the lifetime that lasts from just before calling foo2 to just after it returned (if you would return one of the references the compiler would be forced to extend the corresponding lifetime accordingly, but you don't).
Then it checks if those satisfy the constraitnts placed on foo2 and '4: '4 ('4 lives at least as long as '4) obviously holds. So that bare call is legal.

I though that the compiler would assign 'a lifetime to the a variable and use it, I don't see why it has to infer the lifetimes if a already has a lifetime specified. Thank you for the answer
